# Angular not defined

Tags: php, jquery, errors

I have this code on my website and I don't know why the angular is not being defined and neither is the jquery. I'm fairly new to web development so I don't know what to do with the coding in order for it to work.

The Angular code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('takeawaygrid',['ngSanitize','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap' , 'ngProgress' ,'mgcrea.ngStrap','ngAnimate' ]);

app.filter('dashed', function () {
        return function (text) {                
            var str = text.replace("'", "").replace(/\s+/g, '-');
            return str.toLowerCase();
        };
});


app.filter('html',function($sce){
    return function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
});



app.filter('flatt',function(){
    return function(input){
        var price = 0;
        angular.forEach(input, function(obj , index){
            price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(obj);
        });

        return price;


    }
});




app.controller('GridController',function($scope , $http ,$timeout, ngProgress ,$alert){

    if( angular.isDefined(takeaway_category) ){
        $scope.takeway_category = takeaway_category.data.category_name;
        $scope.spec_cat = takeaway_category.data.cat_all_info;

        $scope.symbol = takeaway_category.data.currency_symbol;

        $scope.per_page = parseInt( takeaway_category.per_page );

    }



    $scope.chnagePrice = function( $event , childId , childPrice , scope , final_price){

        if( !angular.isDefined(final_price)){
                final_price = 0;
        }

        var checkbox = $event.target;
        if( checkbox.checked == true){  

                final_price = parseFloat(childPrice) + parseFloat(final_price);

        }else{

            final_price =  parseFloat(final_price) - parseFloat(childPrice);
        }


        return parseFloat(final_price);

    }


    $scope.selectedChild = function($event , childPrice , childId , selected_child , scope ){
        var checkbox = $event.target;

        if( !angular.isDefined(selected_child)){
                selected_child = [];
        }

        if( checkbox.checked == true ){

            selected_child.push({
                'child_product_id':childId,
                'child_product_price': childPrice
            });

        }else{

            angular.forEach(selected_child , function(child , index){
                    if(child.child_product_id == childId ){
                        selected_child.splice(index,1);
                    }
            });          

        }

        return selected_child;
    }   




    $scope.addToCart = function( post_id, post_price , post_selected_child){

        ngProgress.start();

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=do_add_to_cart' ,
            data: jQuery.param({ 'items': post_selected_child }),
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(e){




            if( e.success == 1 ){



                jQuery('span.amount').html(e.cart);

                    $http({

                        method: 'POST',
                        url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=show_mini_cart',                            
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                    }).success(function(r){

                        jQuery('#mini-cart').html(r); 
                        // jQuery('.header-top-bar .cart-contents').addClass('redbg');
                        // jQuery('#mini-cart').slideDown(250);

                        jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);

                    });


            } 




            $timeout(ngProgress.complete(), 800);
        });

    }




    $scope.addToCartSimple = function(post_id){


        $scope.showLoader = true;


        ngProgress.start();


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=do_add_to_cart_simple',
            data: jQuery.param({ 'id': post_id }),
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(e){                 




            if( e.success == 1 ){

            //  $alert({ content: e.message, placement: 'top', type: 'material', show: true });

                jQuery('span.amount').html(e.cart);

                    $http({

                        method: 'POST',
                        url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=show_mini_cart',                            
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                    }).success(function(r){

                        jQuery('#mini-cart').html(r);
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);

                        // jQuery('.header-top-bar .cart-contents').addClass('redbg');
                        // jQuery('#mini-cart').slideDown(250);

                    });


            } 


            $timeout(ngProgress.complete(), 1000);

            $scope.showLoader = false;
        });

    }














        if( angular.isDefined('takeaway_category') ){

            // $scope.formOption = [];
            // $scope.priceOption = [];

            // $scope.options = takeaway_category.option;

            // $scope.main_price = takeaway_category.main_price;
        }




        $scope.addOption = function( option , id , formOption , new_price  ){

                    var found = jQuery.inArray(option, formOption );
                    if (found >= 0) {
                        // Element was found, remove it.



                        //new_price = parseFloat(new_price) - parseFloat(option.price);




                        // new_price.splice(found ,1);                        
                        formOption.splice(found, 1);
                        new_price[0] = parseFloat(new_price[0]) - parseFloat(option.price);     


                    } else {
                        // Element was not found, add it.

                       // var price = 0;
                       // angular.forEach(new_price , function(obj, index)){

                       //      price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(obj);
                       // }
                       // price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(option.price);


                        // new_pricep[0] = option.price;

                        new_price[0] = parseFloat(new_price[0]) + parseFloat(option.price);   

                        formOption.push(option);
                    }

        }





        $scope.addSelectOption = function(option , id , selectedOption , formOption , price ){

                    if( formOption.length > 0){

                        angular.forEach( formOption , function(obj , index){

                                    if( obj.id == option.id){

                                        price[0] = parseFloat(price[0]) - parseFloat(obj.price);  
                                        formOption.splice(index, 1);                                    
                                        return;
                                    }
                        });

                        if( option.variation == 'yes' ){
                            selectedOption.variation = 'yes';
                        }

                        if( selectedOption != null){


                            if( price[0] == null){
                                price[0] = '0';
                            }

                            price[0] = parseFloat(price[0]) + parseFloat(selectedOption.price);  

                            formOption.push(selectedOption);
                        }


                    }else{

                        if( price[0] == null ){
                            price[0] = '0';
                        }

                        price[0] = parseFloat(price[0]) + parseFloat(selectedOption.price);  



                        formOption.push(selectedOption);
                    }
        }

        // $scope.option.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];



        function check_for_variation(options){

            angular.forEach(options , function(obj , index ){
                if(obj.variation == 'yes'){

                    return true;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }





      $scope.doAddtoCartGrid = function( formOption , price_array , id ){

            // var quantity = 1;
        var quantity1 = angular.element('.p-'+id).val();

        console.log(quantity1);


            var price = 0;

            angular.forEach( price_array , function(obj , index){
                price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(obj);
            });



            $scope.showLoader = true;




            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=do_cart_new',
                data: jQuery.param({ 'quantity' : quantity1 , 'price':price , 'option':formOption , 'product_id':id  }),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function(e){


                if( e.success == 1 ){



                    jQuery('span.amount').html(e.cart);

                        $http({

                            method: 'POST',
                            url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=show_mini_cart',                            
                            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                        }).success(function(r){

                            jQuery('#mini-cart').html(r); 
                            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
                            //jQuery(location.reload(true));

                            // $location.url($location.path());

                         //     var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
                            // $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
                            // $route.reload();

                        });


                } 





                $scope.showLoader = false;
            });


      }




});
```

/**
 *
 @food option
 */

```
var food = angular.module('dyCart',[]);


food.controller('dyController',['$scope','$http', function($scope , $http ){





    if( angular.isDefined('takeaway_category') ){

        $scope.formOption = [];
        $scope.priceOption = [];

        $scope.options = takeaway_category.option;

        $scope.main_price = takeaway_category.main_price;
    }




    $scope.addOption = function(option , id){

                var found = jQuery.inArray(option, $scope.formOption );
                if (found >= 0) {
                    // Element was found, remove it.
                    $scope.formOption.splice(found, 1);

                } else {
                    // Element was not found, add it.
                    $scope.formOption.push(option);
                }                       
    }





        $scope.addSelectOption = function(option , id , selectedOption ){

                    if( $scope.formOption.length > 0){

                        angular.forEach($scope.formOption , function(obj , index){

                                    if( obj.id == option.id){
                                        $scope.formOption.splice(index, 1);                                 
                                        return;
                                    }
                        });

                        if( option.variation == 'yes' ){
                            selectedOption.variation = 'yes';
                        }

                        if( selectedOption != null)
                            $scope.formOption.push(selectedOption);


                    }else{
                         $scope.formOption.push(selectedOption);
                    }

        }




    if( $scope.main_price){

        $scope.price = parseFloat( $scope.main_price ); 

    }else{

        $scope.price = 0.0; 

    }




    $scope.$watchCollection(
        "formOption",
        function( newValue, oldValue ){                     

            if( $scope.main_price){
                $scope.price = parseFloat( $scope.main_price );     
            }else{
                $scope.price = 0.0; 
            }

           angular.forEach(newValue , function(obj , index){

                if( obj.price != null ){
                    $scope.price = parseFloat($scope.price) + parseFloat(obj.price);

                }else{

                    if( obj.selectedOption.price ){
                        $scope.price = parseFloat($scope.price) + parseFloat(obj.selectedOption.price);
                    }

                }                               
           });

        }
    );



    function check_for_variation(options){

        angular.forEach(options , function(obj , index ){
            if(obj.variation == 'yes'){

                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }



  $scope.doAddtoCart = function(){



        // error check 
        var variation = check_for_variation($scope.options);

        // if( variation == false){
        //  alert('Please select Product variation ');
        // }




        var quantity = angular.element('.qty').val();
        var product_id = angular.element('.food_product_id').val();

        // console.log('algjalkd');

        var totalPrice = $scope.price;
        var option = $scope.formOption;

        console.log(product_id);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: takeaway_category.url+'?action=do_cart_new',
                data: jQuery.param({ 'quantity' : quantity , 'price':totalPrice , 'option':option , 'product_id':product_id  }),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function(e){

                // console.log(e);
                jQuery('#mini-cart').html(e); 
                jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
            });                 


  }
```

}]);

The jQuery Code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/**
 * Variations form handling
 */
$('form.variations_form')

    // On clicking the reset variation button
    .on( 'click', '.reset_variations', function( event ) {

        //$(this).closest('form.variations_form').find('.variations input:radio').val('').change();
        //$(this).find('.variations input:radio:checked').each( function() {
            //$(this).checked = false;
        //}
        return false;
    } )

    // Upon changing an option
    .on( 'change', '.variations input:radio', function( event ) {

        $variation_form = $(this).closest('form.variations_form');
        $variation_form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val('').change();

        $variation_form
            .trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_radio_change' )
            .trigger( 'check_variations', [ '', false ] );

        $(this).blur();

        if( $().uniform && $.isFunction( $.uniform.update ) ) {
            $.uniform.update();
        }

    } )

    // Upon gaining focus
    .on( 'focusin', '.variations input:radio', function( event ) {

        $variation_form = $(this).closest('form.variations_form');

        $variation_form
            .trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_radio_focusin' )
            .trigger( 'check_variations', [ $(this).attr('name'), true ] );

    } )

    // Check variations
    .on( 'check_variations', function( event, exclude, focus ) {
        var all_set             = true;
        var any_set             = false;
        var showing_variation   = false;
        var current_settings    = {};
        var $variation_form     = $(this);
        var $reset_variations   = $variation_form.find('.reset_variations');

        $variation_form.find('.variations input:radio:checked').each( function() {

            if ( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
                all_set = false;
            } else {
                any_set = true;
            }

            if ( exclude && $(this).attr('name') == exclude ) {

                all_set = false;
                current_settings[$(this).attr('name')] = '';

            } else {

                // Encode entities
                value = $(this).val()
                    .replace(/&/g, '&')
                    .replace(/"/g, '"')
                    .replace(/'/g, "'")
                    .replace(/</g, '<')
                    .replace(/>/g, '>');

                // Add to settings array
                current_settings[ $(this).attr('name') ] = value;

            }

        });

        var product_id          = parseInt( $variation_form.attr( 'data-product_id' ) );
        var all_variations      = window[ "product_variations_" + product_id ];

        // Fallback
        if ( ! all_variations )
            all_variations = window[ "product_variations" ];

        var matching_variations = find_matching_variations( all_variations, current_settings );

        if ( all_set ) {

            var variation = matching_variations.pop();

            if ( variation ) {
            if ( ! exclude ) {
                $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap').slideDown('200');
            }
                // Found - set ID
                $variation_form
                    .find('input[name=variation_id]')
                    .val( variation.variation_id )
                    .change();

                $variation_form.trigger( 'found_variation', [ variation ] );

            } else {

                // Nothing found - reset fields
                //$variation_form.find('.variations input:radio').val('');
                if ( ! exclude ) {
                $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap').slideUp('200');
            }
                if ( ! focus )
                    $variation_form.trigger( 'reset_image' );

            }

        } else {

            $variation_form.trigger( 'update_variation_values', [ matching_variations ] );

            if ( ! focus )
                $variation_form.trigger( 'reset_image' );

            if ( ! exclude ) {
                $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap').slideUp('200');
            }

        }

        if ( any_set ) {

            if ( $reset_variations.css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
                $reset_variations.css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();

        } else {

            $reset_variations.css('visibility','hidden');

        }

    } )

    // Reset product image
    .on( 'reset_image', function( event ) {

        var $product        = $(this).closest( '.product' );
        var $product_img    = $product.find( 'div.images img:eq(0)' );
        var $product_link   = $product.find( 'div.images a.zoom:eq(0)' );
        var o_src           = $product_img.attr('data-o_src');
        var o_title         = $product_img.attr('data-o_title');
        var o_href          = $product_link.attr('data-o_href');

        if ( o_src && o_href && o_title ) {
            $product_img
                .attr( 'src', o_src )
                .attr( 'alt', o_title )
                .attr( 'title', o_title );
            $product_link
                .attr( 'href', o_href );
        }

    } )

    // Disable option fields that are unavaiable for current set of attributes
    .on( 'update_variation_values', function( event, variations ) {

        $variation_form = $(this).closest('form.variations_form');

        // Loop through selects and disable/enable options based on selections
        $variation_form.find('.variations input:radio').each(function( index, el ){

            current_attr_radio = $(el);

            // Disable all
            current_attr_radio.find('option:gt(0)').attr('checked', 'checked');

            // Get name
            var current_attr_name   = current_attr_radio.attr('name');

            // Loop through variations
            for ( num in variations ) {

                var attributes = variations[ num ].attributes;

                for ( attr_name in attributes ) {

                    var attr_val = attributes[ attr_name ];

                    if ( attr_name == current_attr_name ) {

                        if ( attr_val ) {

                            // Decode entities
                            attr_val = $("<div/>").html( attr_val ).text();

                            // Add slashes
                            attr_val = attr_val.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                            attr_val = attr_val.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");

                            // Compare the meercat
                            current_attr_radio.find('option[value="' + attr_val + '"]').removeAttr('checked');

                        } else {
                            current_attr_radio.find('option').removeAttr('checked');
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        });

        // Custom event for when variations have been updated
        $variation_form.trigger('woocommerce_update_variation_values');

    } )

    // Show single variation details (price, stock, image)
    .on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
        var $variation_form = $(this);

        var $product        = $(this).closest( '.product' );
        var $product_img    = $product.find( 'div.images img:eq(0)' );
        var $product_link   = $product.find( 'div.images a.zoom:eq(0)' );

        var o_src           = $product_img.attr('data-o_src');
        var o_title         = $product_img.attr('data-o_title');
        var o_href          = $product_link.attr('data-o_href');

        var variation_image = variation.image_src;
        var variation_link = variation.image_link;
        var variation_title = variation.image_title;

        $variation_form.find('.variations_button').show();
        $variation_form.find('.single_variation').html( variation.price_html + variation.availability_html );

        if ( ! o_src ) {
            o_src = ( ! $product_img.attr('src') ) ? '' : $product_img.attr('src');
            $product_img.attr('data-o_src', o_src );
        }

        if ( ! o_href ) {
            o_href = ( ! $product_link.attr('href') ) ? '' : $product_link.attr('href');
            $product_link.attr('data-o_href', o_href );
        }

        if ( ! o_title ) {
            o_title = ( ! $product_img.attr('title') ) ? '' : $product_img.attr('title');
            $product_img.attr('data-o_title', o_title );
        }

        if ( variation_image && variation_image.length > 1 ) {
            $product_img
                .attr( 'src', variation_image )
                .attr( 'alt', variation_title )
                .attr( 'title', variation_title );
            $product_link
                .attr( 'href', variation_link );
        } else {
            $product_img
                .attr( 'src', o_src )
                .attr( 'alt', o_title )
                .attr( 'title', o_title );
            $product_link
                .attr( 'href', o_href );
        }

        var $single_variation_wrap = $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap');

        if ( variation.sku )
             $product.find('.product_meta').find('.sku').text( variation.sku );
        else
             $product.find('.product_meta').find('.sku').text('');

        $single_variation_wrap.find('.quantity').show();

        if ( ! variation.is_in_stock && ! variation.backorders_allowed ) {
            $variation_form.find('.variations_button').hide();
        }

        if ( variation.min_qty )
            $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').attr( 'data-min', variation.min_qty ).val( variation.min_qty );
        else
            $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').removeAttr('data-min');

        if ( variation.max_qty )
            $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').attr('data-max', variation.max_qty);
        else
            $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').removeAttr('data-max');

        if ( variation.is_sold_individually == 'yes' ) {
            $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').val('1');
            $single_variation_wrap.find('.quantity').hide();
        }

        $single_variation_wrap.slideDown('200').trigger( 'show_variation', [ variation ] );

    } );

/**
 * Initial states and loading
 */
$('form.variations_form .variations input:radio').change();


/**
 * Helper functions for variations
 */

// Search for matching variations for given set of attributes
function find_matching_variations( product_variations, settings ) {
    var matching = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < product_variations.length; i++) {
        var variation = product_variations[i];
        var variation_id = variation.variation_id;

        if ( variations_match( variation.attributes, settings ) ) {
            matching.push(variation);
        }
    }
    return matching;
}
var count=0;
// Check if two arrays of attributes match
function variations_match( attrs1, attrs2 ) {
    var match = true;
    for ( attr_name in attrs1 ) {
        var val1="";
         var val2="";
        if(count>1)
        {
         val1 = String(attrs1[ attr_name ]).toLowerCase();
         val2 = String(attrs2[ attr_name ]).toLowerCase();
        }
        else
        {
          val1 =attrs1[ attr_name ];
         val2 = attrs2[ attr_name ];
         count++;
        }


        if ( val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined && val1.length != 0 && val2.length != 0 && val1 != val2 ) {
            match = false;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
});

The functionality which isnt working on my website is adding a product option to cart. The website is `http://shahiburrahman.co.uk` . I think because of these issues it is the reason why the functionality isn't working but I may be wrong.

Any help or responses will be much appreciated.

Shahibur

Comment: Do you include the scripts properly? Use [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and add angular and jquery as dependencies. This forces WordPress to load angular and jQuery before your script.

Comment: Hello., they have been included in the HTML file as follows 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shahiburrahman.co.uk/wp-content/themes/takeaway/assets/js/angular-custom.js?ver=4.2.1"></script>

and 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shahiburrahman.co.uk/wp-content/themes/takeaway/assets/js/add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=4.2.1"></script>

where do I add the scripting to? The main HTML page where its being loaded or the functions.php file?

I dont really understand what Im supposed to do with the link you have provided above with regards to the wp_enqueue_script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add the script. The documentation contains information about the function and how it should be used and some helpful examples.

Basically, you will need to add something like this to the `functions.php` file:

```
function myextension_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myextension-angular',
        plugins_url( '/assets/js/angular.min.js' , __FILE__ ),
        // If you are working on a theme, not a plugin,
        // replace the above line with this:
        // get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/angular.min.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myextension-angular-custom',
        plugins_url( '/assets/js/angular-custom.js' , __FILE__ ),
        // If you are working on a theme, not a plugin,
        // replace the above line with this:
        // get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/angular-custom.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'myextension-angular' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myextension-add-to-cart-variation',
        plugins_url( '/assets/js/add-to-cart-variation.min.js' , __FILE__ ),
        // If you are working on a theme, not a plugin,
        // replace the above line with this:
        // get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/add-to-cart-variation.min.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'myextension-angular' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myextension_enqueue_scripts' );
```

**Edit:** I thought the file `angular-custom.js` contained angular, however, I just recognized you split the code into the two files and don't even include angular. I adapted the code to include a third file, `angular.min.js`, which you need to [download](https://angularjs.org/) and add.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code above didnt make a difference and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Shahibur Check whether the scripts were included in the correct order by looking at the HTML. Check the debugging console of your browser for errors while loading the scripts. It seems like you are working on a theme, did you adapt my code according to my comments? I accidentally skipped the `/assets/` parts of your URLs, make sure to check my updated code.

Comment: Hi, ok I am going to doing the checks now, I've implemented the code back in and I am still getting the same error message of it is not defined, anonymous function. The /assets/ part i put in because it is found in the directory of the website there WP-content/themes/takeaway/assets/js/angular-custom.js

I may just be going thick and not knowing whats going on having been looking at this code all day but its still throwing me the same error message

Comment: Did you comment out the `plugins_url..` line and uncomment the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` lines as mentioned in the comments since you are working in your theme directory?

Comment: @czerspalace yes I have done that and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you download and add angular to match the path in the code provided? As mentioned, you need to download and add to the `assets/js/` directory. Going to this url gives a 404 http://shahiburrahman.co.uk/wp-content/themes/takeaway/assets/js/angular.min.js

Comment: @czerspalace Hi, Yes I've added it correctly now and the error has gone. Thanks for that. I'm trying to figure out an issue I'm having with my products page if i choose to add an option such as with mushrooms and click add to cart only the original product gets added, no add on. Not sure whats going wrong here :/ an example can be found here http://shahiburrahman.co.uk/product/chicken-achar/

Comment: @Shahibur Please accept this answer if it was the solution to your problem. For further help with a different problem, you may ask a new question, if it complies with the SE's policy.